# Access Google Sheet with service account in Java

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I am currently working on an app that connects with google sheets through OAuth client Id, I was wondering if there's a way to do same thing using service account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a Google Workspace administrator then yes, you will be able to use [domain wide delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106) in order to impersonate an user of your domain and allow the service account to make changes on it's behalf. Be aware that the service account will only work with Google Workspace users, it doesn't work with regular @gmail.com accounts. So if your app is considering only Google Workspace users you will be able to do this.

You can check how impersonation works by checking this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)

Comment: do you have an example, because I am new to Java.